# lstlisting with c++: spaces around scope resolution operator

Tags: listings, sourcecode, letterspacing

I am having a hard time to make the output of *lstlisting* for c++ source look good. Currently, I am stuck with a problem to reduce the amount of space around the scope resolution operator `::`. See the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{ %
language=C++,
basicstyle=\footnotesize,
captionpos=b,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
  hello::world
\end{lstlisting}

The amount of space \lstinline{is::too} damn high.

\end{document}
```

The output of this is shown in the picture below, where I marked the spaces that upset me. [image: spaces around the scope-resolution operator].

Do you guys know a way to configure this behaviour? I couldn't find something in lstlistings documentation.

Comment: If you add `otherkeywords={::}`, then the `::` are printed darker as a keyword and even though this does not change the spacing, it does not look as bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `columns=fullflexible`, eliminates the spacing:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{%
    language=C++,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,
    captionpos=b,
    otherkeywords={::},
%columns=fullflexible
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
  hello::world 
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[columns=fullflexible]
  hello::world    // columns=fullflexible
\end{lstlisting}

Without \verb|columns=fullflexible| \lstinline{is::too} 

With \verb|columns=fullflexible| \lstinline[columns=fullflexible]{is::too} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `literate={<search>}{<replace>}<size>` you have replace `<search>` with `<replace>` of width `<size>`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
\lstset{
  language=C++,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize,
  captionpos=b
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
  hello::world
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[literate={::}{::}1]
  hello::world
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Literate programming is discussed in section **5.4 Literate programming** (p 48) of the [`listings` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

I beg to differ with the other answers, which are kind of *workarounds* instead of a solution. Does the way your editor/IDE displays `::` not go to your liking? All you need to get the same look is use a monospace font (`\ttfamily`), which should always be used to display code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  language=C++,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No, I am not satisfied with the output. gvim displays everything just fine ;)

Comment: I disagree that code should be typeset in a monospace font. See e.g. the C++ book by Stroustrup.