# spacing before scope resolution operator

Tags: spacing, listings, sourcecode

I'm new to LaTeX and I have encountered a problem with the listings package, I have a space before the `::` operator of C++ .

after reading [lstlisting with c++: spaces around scope resolution operator](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47737/lstlisting-with-c-spaces-around-scope-resolution-operator) I added `columns=fullflexible` but it doesn't solve the problem.

here are my settings :

```
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,                                                           
   frame=lrtb ,
   columns=fullflexible      
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.